# I want users to always see the Facebook pop-up on login

Tags: facebook

I have a site that logs in using Facebook.  The first time a user logs in, they get a pop up from Facebook explaining all the parts of the user FB profile my site will have access to.  After accepting once, though, they don't get this pop-up on subsequent visits.  Is there a way I can ensure that the user *always* sees this popup?

**Update:**

I'm trying to find a way to do this during development, so that I can see the list every time.  I don't really need this in production.

Answer (score 0):

they see it because it's the standard OAuth workflow to accept the terms of the application they are authorizing through facebook. Once the auth is complete, they are sent directly through, no reason to ask them for auth over and over.

EDIT:
Based on your update, the list is visible through your application settings in Facebook. you can use facebook's api to get these users.

Answer (score -1):

You can build a "Fake Login" - there you can show your terms again. So your clients got a better feeling. ;-)

Comment: That's kind of what I'm doing.  And, I guess that's more in line with what I'm looking for, which is a way to call this out while I'm developing.